# R - datatable prefilter values

Tags: r, dt

I have code like this I render it via markdown

```
iris2 = iris[c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ]
datatable(iris2, filter = 'top', options = list(
  pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE
))
```

Before table renders how can I “prefilter” value, for example setosa and hide other values in column? It should be filtered in input Species column, once user will delete it, everything should be visible again

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing against using the [`select2` filters](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTselect2Filters.html), you can do as follows:

```r
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

iris2 = iris[c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ]
dat <- iris2

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(), lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      lapply(c(0, 1:ncol(dat)), function(i) tags$th(id = paste0("th", i)))
    )
  )
)

js <- function(colindex, selected){
  c(
    "function(){", 
    sprintf("  var colindex = %d, selected = '%s';", colindex, selected),
    "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
    "    var column = this;",
    "    var $select =",
    "      $('<select multiple=\"multiple\">' +",
    "         '<option value=\"\"></option>' +",
    "      '</select>')",
    "      .appendTo($('#th'+i).empty())", 
    "      .on('change', function(){",
    "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(idx, element){",
    "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
    "        }).toArray().join('|');",
    "        column.search(",
    "          vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false",
    "        ).draw();",
    "      });",
    "    var data = column.data();",
    "    if(i == 0){",
    "      data.each(function(d, j){",
    "        $select.append('<option value=\"' + d + '\">' + d + '</option>');",
    "      });",
    "    }else{",
    "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
    "        var s = colindex == i && selected == d ? 'selected=\"selected\" ': ''; console.log(s);",
    "        $select.append('<option ' + s + 'value=\"' + d + '\">' + d + '</option>');",
    "      });",
    "    }",
    "    $select.select2({width: '100%', closeOnSelect: false});",
    "    setTimeout(function(){$select.trigger('change');});",
    "  });",
    "}")
}

htmlDep <- htmlDependency(
  name = "select2", 
  version = "4.0.13", 
  src = normalizePath("./path/to/select2"), # path to the folder containing the 'select2' files 
  script = "select2.min.js", 
  stylesheet = "select2.min.css", 
  all_files = FALSE
)

dtable <- 
  datatable(
    dat, 
    container = sketch, 
    options = list(
      orderCellsTop = TRUE,
      initComplete = JS(js(colindex = 5, selected = "setosa")),
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
      )
    )
  )
dtable[["dependencies"]] <- c(dtable[["dependencies"]], list(htmlDep))
dtable
```